# How can I fix the mouse lag on the PC version of Dead Space?

Tags: pc, mouse, dead-space

When I try and play the PC version of Dead Space the mouse is sluggish and unresponsive regardless of how high I set the sensitivity. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: wow, I thought that was on purpouse -- It makes for a good survival horror mechanic

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver Poor gameplay never makes for a good mechanic.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Usually this means that vertical sync is set, and you need to unset it, it's one of the most annoying things ever from computers that are slightly behind recommended specs.

Comment: Vsync is totally broken in DS1.  It works fine is DS2, but hooooly goodness is it awful in DS1.  I couldn't even believe I was playing the same game after I disabled it!

Comment: That's not entirely correct. This problem is also present on computers which are above the system requirements. I have an Core2Duo with 2.8GHz per Core, 4GiB RAM and a GeForce 9600GT...and with vsync on it's unplayable because the mouse moves so slow.

Comment: @Bobby, same here. Modern rigs will have trouble until you turn that off.

Comment: I can confirm that v-sync is terrible in Dead Space 1. Turn it off and use a different program (e.g. Nvidia Control Panel or AMD CCC) to force it on. If you have a powerful modern PC, you'll most likely need to turn v-sync on in some way if you intend to keep playing after getting the Plasma Cutter.

Answer (score 4):

There is a fix for that called [Dead Space Mouse Fix](http://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/840-dead-space-mouse-fix/).

This will give you raw mouse input, it changes everything!
I would also suggest to use [Widescreen Fixer](https://github.com/dlrudie/WidescreenFixer/releases) software to get wider FOV.

Answer (score 1):

Most new GPU's with more then 900Mhz clock speeds will have problems with this game because the GPU proccessing everything way to fast as the game was meant to be played at 30FPS originally. I lowered my clock speeds using MSI afterburner and it helped a lot with the mouse problems (tho the GPU runs at 450mhz the game still goes over 150+ fps in some areas)