# How can I make the sensitivity reasonable?

Tags: dead-space

I was having a mouse lag issue in Dead Space, and I followed the useful instructions [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26636/how-can-i-fix-the-mouse-lag-on-the-pc-version-of-dead-space) which completely solved that problem.

It introduced another problem, however, which is that the mouse sensitivity is very, very low even when the sensitivity bar in the options is turned all the way up. Luckily I have an expensive gaming mouse and I can increase the sensitivity on the mouse to make it playable, but it's *still* too low even after doing that. When I right click to aim, sweeping the mouse over a foot turns the view about 30 degrees.

It's more playable than it was with the mouse lag, but this is a problem too. Is there any way to remove mouse lag but still have reasonably high sensitivity?

Comment: perhaps a third party program to amp your mouse sensitivity even more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to cope, which isn't an amazing solution but definitely makes the game at least playable again, is to boost the crap out of the sensitivity using an out-of-game initialization file.

In order to do that, navigate to:

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Electronic Arts\Dead Space`

Modify the settings.txt file and set the sensitivity higher. I set it to 4 (the in-game maximum is 1) and that seems pretty decent.

There are some drawbacks to this, however. Aiming and turning in-game are much improved by this, but controlling the mouse out of combat becomes impossible because the mouse rockets to the other side of the screen with just the slightest of touches. Get used to navigating menus with the keyboard if you want to use this method. Even navigating the map becomes a challenge because apparently mouse sensitivity is linked to map turn speed with the arrow keys.

The game's PC controls are flawed at best, but this at least makes it playable.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution, another mouse driver.

- (not nessecary for xp): Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider
- driver: moudrv_20080201
- gui: MouDrvGUI

You can set mouse movement as fast as neccecary.

Comment: This...provides nothing but a name.  Care to provide a few more details?